# Why Hilt and Dagger need to inject Activity and Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have been using Dagger for a while and now I'm starting to migrate to Hilt, but I don't understand the benefits of injecting Activity and Fragment.
In Dagger, it is `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` and something like `HasActivityInjector`

Sorry if it was a stupid question.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a benefit, it is a constraint imposed by Android. Activities and Fragments are instantiated by Android, not by the developer or the DI framework, and as such, they require special treatment. [It is the same in Dagger actually](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#injecting-activities).

In Hilt you don't need to write that code manually anymore, [you can just annotate the Application, Activity and Fragment using special notations](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes), the library will take care of generating the corresponding code.